# java 3D drawing

Tags: java, 3d, drawing

I have a matrix that includes X-Y-Z coordinates of an environment.  I want to render this matrix in a 3D view, coloring the coordinates in terms of  depth.  For example, the coordinates are taken from a room, so I'd like this 3D view screen as room screen.  How can I do that in Java?

Comment: Please don't flag your questions with terms like "Urgent".

Comment: More formal writing style and more time spent asking your question will improve your chances of people exerting effort to help you.

Comment: I've cleaned up your writing a bit, but you need to clarify the 3rd sentence.  Have you written any code?  3D programming can be very challenging.  It's hard for people to help when they don't know how advanced you are.

Comment: Which part exactly are you stuck on: the math, Java, Java3D, visual design, all of the above?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a specific question related to programming (in Java), I'l lrecommend you go through the Java 3D tutorial from Sun: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/java3d/

You could of course wait for someone to serve you this on a silver platter, but if you then need something changed, you can't do it, because you don't understand any of it.

Better start learning yourself.

Good luck!